# None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{ }{IPAddress}{IPADDRESS:9300}]

Tags: scala, cassandra, elasticsearch-5, elastic4s, elassandra

While establishing the connection with elassandra cluster through elastic4s getting the follow error.

NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{…}{IPAddress{IPAddress:9300}]]

```
  val settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "Test Cluster").build()
  val client = TcpClient.transport(settings, ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://ClusterIP:9300"))
```